# Why is my Word document losing connection to its template?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2010, templates

My client is having a problem with a Word template I've provided for them on their site.

Specifically:

- They've placed the template on a shared drive (Windows mapped network drive) that everyone can see at the same path.
- They can create a new document based on that template, save that new document to their desktop and work with that document fine, including using macros from the original template.
- **However**: when emailed from Original Author A to Editor B, the document at Editor B's end loses its connection to the template. Macros saved in the template are unusable. I've brought up the Microsoft VBA window (alt-F11) and confirmed that there is no reference to the template in the document at Editor B's end.

I've confirmed that Editor B can see the original template on the shared drive.

I can't reproduce this problem locally using my companies own infrastructure, so I suspect that this is something specific to my clients (A) network setup or (B) Word 2007 setup.

The client has added the template location to the trust center "trusted locations" on both the sending and receiving computers. "Allow trusted locations on my network" is checked.

I have a few ideas for things I want to check out next time I'm on site - under the "trust center" settings there's a list of trusted locations for templates and various security settings related to templates. I'd also like to try reattaching the template to the emailed document after the fact to see if I get any interesting error messages.

What else can I do to work this problem out?

Comment: Macros sound like a security issue. As far as losing the template, I am pretty sure that is intentional.

Comment: @soandos: Both the macros and the link to the template transition across fine when emailing documents based on the template around in my office. How is this supposed to work otherwise? Surely there's some way to email a template based document and have template functionality still work?

Comment: @soandos: And the URL at http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/deploy-your-word-macros-from-a-central-location-HA001087294.aspx explicitly states that this should work - I'm suspecting security settings somewhere at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to some obscure way Word uses to "attach" templates to documents. I'm having a nightmare trying to distribute a new template across our department. At least I have found how to manage the attachment of templates:

Try the following (Word 2010): File, Options, Add-Ins (in left list). On the bottom you will see "Manage" and a combo box. You can choose "Templates" in the combo box, click "Go to", and you have arrived at Word's interface for attaching templates. It might be a way to work around your problem.